# what is the latitude longitude relation with the Poles(North, South, East, West)?

Tags: android, gps, compass

I am trying to Understand that What happens to the Latitude longitude when moving to North or south or east or West.

Suppose My current GPS coordinates are;
Latitude = 33.659832  Longitude = 72.345678

Now what will be New Latitude/Longitude 30 METERS to the North of my position  also tell me towards south, east and west direction.
Please be specific thanks

Comment: For North and south only it is a simple math https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry) for East and west depends on latitude... The Google search should returns some answers,  did you try any?

Comment: none of the research gave me an exact answer that's why I came here. but I was using the website "latitude longitude finder"  and then moving to different positions to see the changes it helped a little bit. But I need an exact answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latitude is related to South -> North
If you move North, the latitude increases, if moving south it decreases.

Longitude is related to West -> East
If you move East, the longitude increases until 180 and when you cross that datum limit it jumps to -180.

If you want to calculate a new coordinate by offset meters and direction,
you find code here at stackoverflow.

To play with coordinates you can use http://www.geomidpoint.com/destination/
where you enter the coordinate and the offset in km, and the compass direction in degrees.

The calculation is done either using

1. complex spherical formulas for calculation of big distances > 1km - 10km or
2. using school mathematics (Polar coordinates (r, phi) once you have
   converted the lat, lon to cartesian space, e.g using a
   equirectangular projection. That is suitable only for smaller distances less than about 10km